# I would like to use the selection from the material table but it's not working - Material Table Selection

Tags: typescript, angular-material-table

My problem is that I would like to use the selection from the material table but for some reason it has its place in the surface, but the checkbox does not appear.

This is my HTML code:

```html
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-elevation-z8>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
       <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
          [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
          [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
       </mat-checkbox>
     </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
       <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
          (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
          [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
          [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
       </mat-checkbox>
     </td>
    </ng-container>

  <!-- ... -->

  </table>
```

And my TS file:

```js
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';

export abstract class MyClass implements OnInit {
    devizas: DevizaInterface[] = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'dollar',
      code: 'USD' ,
    }
    //...
  ];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<DevizaInterface>(devizas);
  selection = new SelectionModel<DevizaInterface> (true, []);

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  checkboxLabel(row?: PeriodicElement): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.id + 1}`;
  }

}
```

I did everything as it is written in the documentation, nothing wrong with the other functions (sorting, filtering).
In app.module.ts I imported everything I needed for this.
What might be the problem? Which part did I not write well for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put:
**displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'id', 'name', 'code'];**
and call it from your HTML file:  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"> (it will render your columns).

The crucial is not to forget to add in the displayed columns '**select**' field, because it also presents a column with the checkboxes, as it other fields which are part of the interface.